# Generate Text Inside a ScrollView with Vertically and Horizontally

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, textview, scrollview

So.. I guess the topic might be a little bit confusing. Actually what I want to do here is:

(1)  ScrollView x 1

(2)  TextViews inside the ScrollView are aligned Horizontally and also vertically

(3)  TextViews should be generated by code

The following images might explain what exactly what I want to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points to post image directly, so posting the link of it is what I can do for now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

The image shows the result I want, is it possible to generate TextView in that way?

I have no idea on generating textviews that are already inside a LinearLayout and the LinearLayout should also be placed inside a ScrollView. It seems complicated. Not sure did I explain it well, hope there is a way to do it.

Thanks FOR Helping!!

Comment: Could you at least show the code/what you have so far! Also I'd recommend using ConstraintLayout instead of a LinearLayout.

Comment: After looking at your comment, i realized I might be too persist in using Linear Layout, constraint layout might be a better method for doing this. There are some ideas for me to try now. Thanks for helping @mtotoWamkwe

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: If your TextViews are dynamically generated, I'd recommend using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Also to be able to scroll in both directions, use RecyclerView inside Horizontal NestedScrollView.